# Chicken scheme compiler (csc) errors

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I have a fresh install of mingw64 and chicken scheme but whenever I try to compile a file with `csc` from the command line I get the following:
[image]

```
error: shell command terminated with non-zero exit status 1: "gcc" "foo.o" -o "foo" -wl,--enable-auto-import -Lc:\chicken-iup\lib -L"c:\chicken-iup/lib/" -lchicken -lm -lws2_32"
```

foo.scm:

```
(define (fac n)
  (if (zero? n)
      1
      (* n (fac (- n 1)))))
(write (fac 10))
(newline)
```

Could someone help in figuring out why it cant compile the file? If I have a file browser open to the C:\chicken-iup\ folder I can see it makes a .c file and then makes an .o file. The error happens I assume during the linking of the .o file but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using [`chicken-iup`](http://www.kiatoa.com/cgi-bin/chicken-iup/home). Looking at its web page, it looks like it's designed to work with mingw, and not mingw-w64. The "incompatible" libraries are probably because mingw-w64 is designed to link in 64-bit libraries, but the `chicken-iup` libraries were 32-bit.

If you want to use mingw-w64, you probably have to compile CHICKEN yourself.

Comment: So I can do a fresh install of mingw and it might work? Should I reinstall chicken again after mingw